# python: compare datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im new using python. I have a dataframe with 3 columns (id, beg, end) what to search clients that was connected to our website on the 2021-09-09 like shown in the expected ouput below.

```
id  beg                      end                    field1      field2
x1  2021-09-08 10:00:00      2021-09-10 10:00:00                24:00:00
x2  2021-09-09 22:00:00      2021-09-10 00:00:00    00:00:00    22:00:00
x3  2021-09-08 10:00:00      2021-09-09 10:00:00    00:00:00    10:00:00
```

**My attempt**

```
if (df['beg'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == df['end'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')):
df['field1'] = df['beg']
df['field2'] = df['end']
else: 
df['field2'] = '24:00:00'
```

Comment: search for `np.where`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
mask = df['beg'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == df['end'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['field1'] = np.where(mask, df['beg'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), '')
df['field2'] = np.where(mask, df['end'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), '24:00:00')
```

Or:

```
df['field1'] = df['beg'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').where(mask, '')
df['field2'] = df['end'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').where(mask, '24:00:00')
```

Comment: thank you but im gotting this error TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: Maybe `df['beg']/df['end']` are datetime type. You want `strftime` again.